# When do binomial distributions occur?

Tags: st.statistics, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-trial, pr.probability

A binomial distribution is the distribution of the number of successes of n independent, identical Bernoulli trials.  What happens when the trials are dependent and the Bernoulli trials are not identical by which I mean that the probability of success from trial to trial varies?  How identical and close to independent do they have to be before we see something that resembles a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking, I think, when a [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) holds.  The simplest form of the CLT is that the binomial distributions Binomial(n,p), suitably rescaled, converge to a normal distribution as n goes to infinity.  (This binomial case is usually not called the CLT, but goes under the name of the [de Moivre-Laplace theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).)

Now, a Binomial(n,p) random variable is the sum of n Bernoulli(p) random variables.  The usual form of the CLT states that if $S\_n = X\_1 + ... + X\_n$, where the $X\_i$ are independent and identically distributed with mean μ and standard deviation σ, then $(S\_n - \mu n)/(\sigma \sqrt{n})$ converges in distribution to the standard normal as n → ∞.

If the $X\_i$ are in fact dependent, see the link provided by Ori Gurel-Gurevich above.

If the $X\_i$ are independent but *not* identically distributed, then there are two standard conditions for proving that the rescaled distribution of $S\_n = X\_1 + ... + X\_n$ converges to the standard normal: [Lindeberg's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) and [Lyapunov's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_condition).  Both are a bit difficult to understand when you first look at them.  But the basic idea behind both of them is that if no one of the summands $X\_i$ is too large (in variance) compared to the others, then the normal distribution still appears.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your setting, it might better to consider the asymptotic when $n\rightarrow \infty$, which gives you a Poisson distribution. There are various conditions, weaker than independence, under which Poisson approximation holds. For example, take a look [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/Lectures/lec2.61-chen-stein.pdf).

Comment: Also at Pemantle's web page (http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/full-year-webpage.html) are links to two articles by Arratia, Goldstein, and Gordon on which the lecture you linked to is based. 

Answer (score 0):

The distribution you describe is called a **Poisson-binomial distribution**.  If you do a search with this name you will find a substantial literature on it.